# Create dynamic row-column table grid in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, html-table, datatable

I'm trying to create a `row-column` table grid (spreadsheet-like) in Vue.js. Right now I have achieved the functionality I'm looking for, but the code is somewhat dirty. Basically the component is initialized with the row and column names and I want to create an input field for each cell so the user can edit the cell's value. Note that the final table will be submitted to the server (that's why I'm creating the `records` array). Any suggestions to make the code more clean would be appreciated.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarotnem/yr7w2gp5/2/)

**Vue Component**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    columns: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    rows: ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    records: []
  },
  mounted() {
    this.rows.forEach(row => {
      this.records.push({
        row: row,
        details: []
      });
    });

    this.records.forEach(record => {
      this.columns.forEach(column => {
        record.details.push({
          column: column,
          value: 0
        });
      });
    });
  }
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th v-for="(column, columnIndex) in columns" :key="columnIndex">{{column}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(record, rowIndex) in records" :key="rowIndex">
          <td>{{record.row}}</td>
          <td v-for="(detail, index) in record.details" :key="index">
              <input type="text" v-model="detail.value">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit based on comments:

There is nothing wrong with using forEach(). For readability I would suggest using two methods that describe what you are using in each step. If you wanted to use another array method you could chain .map() but it's essentially doing the same thing

```
methods: {
    setRecords(){
        this.records = this.rows.map(row => ({
           row: row,
           details: this.columns.map(column => ({
              column: column,
              value: 0
           }))
        }))
      }
  }
```

---

Original:

I would suggest simplifying `records` to `[ {colName: value, ...}, ...]` then looping over columns within the table row

Table Row:

```
<tr v-for="(record, rowIndex) in records" :key="rowIndex">
    <td>{{record.row}}</td>
    <td v-for="(col, index) in columns" :key="index">
        <input type="text" v-model="record[col]">
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

From your data you can format records using`mounted() { this.records = this.rows.map(row => this.columns.reduce((acc, col) => ({...acc, ...{[col]: 0}}), {}))}`

Comment: Even though the code you provided is very interesting I'm looking for a different format in the final records array, like the one my original code is producing. My concern is about using multiple `forEach` in my original code, I'm sure there is a better (and more complex) way to achieve this result.